# Find the particular solution of the equation that satisfies condition

Tags: calculus, integration

Full question: Find the particular solution of the equation $f'(x) = 4x^{-1/2}$ that satisfies the condition $f(1) = 12$.

I have $f'(x) = 4x^{-1/2}$ and am given that $f(1) = 12$.

I took the integral of $4x^{-1/2}$ and got $8x^{1/2}$. I know the integral is correct but when I plug 1 into $8x^{1/2}$, I do not get $12$.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you integrate an indefinite integral, you need to include a **constant of integration** to the result.

So, you need to evaluate $f(1) = 12$ given $f(x) = 8x^{1/2} + C$  to determine the required constant C.

Comment: Downvoter: Any reason for the downvote other than personal spite?

Comment: same downvoter on my post, too.

Comment: So I would do $8(1)^{1/2}$ + C = 12? Which would be 4.

Comment: Yes, exactly. So the particular solution would be $f(x) = 8^{1/2} + 4$.

Comment: You're welcome, yayu!

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to add your constant! You should get the antiderivative to be $f'(x) = 8x^{1/2} + C = 12$ at $x = 1$, so then solve for $C$.

Indeed, when you anti-differentiate a function, you end up with a whole family of functions each differing by a constant. This is why you need to find the **particular** solution.

Comment: Thank you for helping as well! I'll try not to forget the constant next time.

Answer (score 3):

If $f'(x)=4 \cdot x^{-\frac{1}{2}}$   then

$f(x)=\text{integration of } f'(x)dx$

which is equal to $8 \cdot x^{\frac{1}{2}}+c \tag{1} $

Here c is some constant.

Now given that $f(1) = 12$ (given above line):

$f(1) = 8\cdot 1^{\frac{1}{2}} + c = 12$

Therefore from above line we can say that
$c=4 \tag{2}$

Therefore from equation (1) & (2)

The particular solution of the given function is

$f(x) = 8\cdot x^{\frac{1}{2}} + 4$